# I'm using YII2, I'm displaying a list of inactive users. I'm using the checkbox to select the user. I'm going to send an email to the user I tagged

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, yii2

$user

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | user 1 |
| 002 | User 2 |

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($user as $user( { ?>
    <input class="is-selected" type="checkbox" value="<?= $value->user->id ?>" />
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<button type="submit" class="btn is-primary">Send Reminder</button>
```

I'm using YII2, I'm displaying a list of inactive users. I'm using the checkbox to select the user. I'm going to send an email to the user I tagged.

how can i get id value from that checkbox and send data to controller?

I try to use javascript/jquery but i can't solved yet, i need some help from you guys

Answer (score 0):

The above screenshot and your implementation is like you are talking 2 different things.

You would just be required a Grid View with CheckboxColumn

```
<?php

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Html;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'id' => 'user_form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'lfp-listing']
]);
echo Html::submitButton('Send Reminder', ['class' => 'btn is-primary', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'send_reminder']);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'checkboxOptions' =>
            function ($model) {
                return ['value' => $model->id, 'class' => '', 'id' => 'checkbox'];
            }
        ],
    ]
]);
ActiveForm::end();
```

Considering your Action is actionIndex()

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['selection']) && 'send_reminder' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($_REQUEST['selection'] as $userIds) {
                //write down the email code here....
            }
}
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, now i finished my question with another reference.
thank you I appreciate your participation, you're amaizing